# Opencv-python error when everything is alright

Tags: python, opencv

i am getting the following error

`"TypeError: _locateAll_python() got an unexpected keyword argument 'confidence'"`

So the thing is everything works perfectly on my PC but it doesn't work on my other one..

I have installed pyautogui, opencv, pywin32
I also tried every single version of python
I also tried to upgrade pillow, opencv, pip
on my main PC i have no problems, however on my secondary PC nothing would work..

I tried everything and im just losing hope
I really need to get that thing to work because i coded a bot and i need it to go 24/7 on my second PC because i use my main PC for work.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUhz1.png)

Please see the full error in the picture and if you have any ideas on how it can be fixed i will be extremly grateful